# Async pipe value with router events always null

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've got a pretty straight-forward issue when trying to access an async property in my template - the value returned is always null. The method is the following:

```
someAsyncProperty():Observable<string> {
    return this._router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(event => 'my value');
}
```

In my template, `{{someAsyncProperty() | async}}` renders nothing.

In my template, `{{(someAsyncProperty() | async) | json}}` renders null.

If I alter my async method to be something like:

```
someAsyncProperty():Observable<string> {
    return Observable.of(true)
        .map(event => 'my value');
}
```

...the values in the template render correctly.

I'm not sure what the issue here is. Is using the `async` pipe with router events not possible or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
someAsyncProp$:Observable<string>;
constructor() {
  this.someAsyncProp$ = this.someAsyncProperty();
}
```

```
{{someAsyncProp$ | async}}
```

otherwise a new subscription is created (`someAsyncProperty()` called) every time change detection runs.